# Rails Mongoid show all documents using "where"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, mongoid

I try to pass value as parameter, to array:

**Controller:**

```
@users = User.all.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page]).order(sort_by => sort_order).where(type: {'$all': ["#{params[:type]}"] })
```

Now, is it possible to find all document from collection using:

```
.where(type: {'$all': ['something_to_find_all_from type:'] })
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, params[:type] is an array, you can search all users using where, and thereafter sort these results using order. You can find a similar example [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#scoping).

```
@users = User.where(:type.in => params[:type]).order(sort_by => sort_order).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
```

If you're looking for a translated mongoid query you can check out [this](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#where) link

Your query might then read something like
    `User.where(:type.all => params[:type])`

Comment: Nope, i have ActionView:Template::Error (The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command) i try  .where(type: {'$all': ["#{params[:type]}"] }) and it works.

Comment: @Mike Can you elaborate your question? and post model code and value of "params[:type]" ? I've also added a link above to help you formulate mongoid queries.